# Pandas: Count frequency of column combinations (when coded 0/1)

Tags: pandas

Sorry for the title, but I'm not sure how to formulate it. I have a set of samples in a pandas DataFrame, with a set of columns indicating the activation of certain conditions. For example

```
ex = pd.DataFrame({
    "cond_1" : [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    "cond_2" : [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    "cond_3" : [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
})

ex = ex.assign(total=ex.sum(axis=1))

|    | cond_1 | cond_2 | cond_3 | total |
| 0  |   1    |   0    |    0   |   1   |
| 1  |   1    |   0    |    1   |   2   |
| 2  |   1    |   1    |    0   |   2   |
| 3  |   1    |   0    |    1   |   2   |
| 4  |   0    |   1    |    1   |   2   |
| 5  |   1    |   1    |    1   |   3   |
```

I'm interested in the cases where the *total* column has a value of 2, since in the cases of 1 and 3, I have just one or all conditions activated, respectively. I would like to be able to obtain a DataFrame indicating the number of times that a certain combination of conditions is activated. Something such as the following (just for the cases tot=2)

```
|    | cond_12 | cond_13 | cond_23 |
| 2  |    1    |    2    |    1    |
```

or (using un stack)

```
| 2  | cond_12 | 1 | 
|    | cond_13 | 2 | 
|    | cond_23 | 1 |
```

Is there any way of performig this operations? I have more conditions, so I'd like to perform some kind of groupby by *total* and obtain these combinations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you expect 4 result rows of combinations for the `total = 2` ?

Comment: Just for total=2, I would expect three rows, indicating the combinations 110 (cond_12), 101(cond_13), and 011 (cond_23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

```
s = (ex[ex['total'].eq(2)]
 [['cond_1', 'cond_2', 'cond_3']]
 .value_counts()
)
```

Output:

```
cond_1  cond_2  cond_3
1       0       1         2
0       1       1         1
1       1       0         1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively:

```
cols = ['cond_1', 'cond_2', 'cond_3']

name = ex[cols] @ pd.Series(cols).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).values

out = (ex[['total']].join('cond_'+name.rename('cond'))
       .value_counts(sort=False)
       .sort_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
total  cond    
1      cond_1      1
2      cond_12     1
       cond_13     2
       cond_23     1
3      cond_123    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems appropiate, I'll check the operations to understand them. I have not use "@" before.

Comment: @tms this is called a dot product, this is a trick to concatenate the letters where there is `1` into a single string